# Node.js v12.x how to set Error.code property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

In newer versions of Node (post version 9 I believe) they have standardized on returning Error objects that contain properties such as error.code. I have tried constructing an Error object and setting the property but get an error:

```
let err = new Error('sample error');
error.code = 'BADERR';
```

What is the correct way to leverage the new node.js properties in the Error class?

Answer (score 0):

With modern javascript you'd just extend the `Error` class:

```
class BadError extends Error {
    constructor (message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = 'BADERR';
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let err = new BadError('sample error');
```

Traditionally you'd do the exact same thing but using prototypes:

```
function BadError (message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = 'BADERR';
}

BadError.prototype = new Error();
```

Or the slightly less traditional but still traditional way:

```
function BadError (message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.code = 'BADERR';
}

BadError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```